# send data from express middleware to server.js for socketio to emit to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I need to send data from NodeJS to React frontend. I am using socketio to emit the data.

But the problem is that the data that I need to emit is generating in express middleware file which is then storing to MongoDB and also being used in a router file.

I am not sure how to send the data to server.js. Also if it is possible or there is another way to do it.

This is my middleware file:

```js
module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
  const urlCode = req.originalUrl.slice(1);

  const geturl = await Url.findOne({ urlCode });

  if (geturl) {
    const id = geturl._id;

    try {
      let oldclicks = geturl.clicks;
      const addclicks = {
        clicks: oldclicks + 1,
      };
      let newclicks = oldclicks + 1;
      
      // This is the data that I need to send to server.js
      const response = await Url.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: geturl._id },
        { $set: addclicks },
        { new: true }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.json('No URL found');
  }

  next();
};
```

This is my socketio setup in server.js:

```js
// Socket IO
const server = http.createServer(app);
var io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('New Connection');
  // Here I will fetch the data from middleware and then will emit to client
  socket.emit('message', 'working connection to server');
});
```

Comment: You'll have to put a `socket.emit` along the line and a `socket.on` on the socket io server

Comment: This is not a socket io issue, at least not yet. But the issue is I don't know how to pass the data from middleware to server.js where I have initiated socket io.

Comment: Are both pieces if code on the same app or are you writing socket io on a different app?

Comment: same app just different pages. socket io is on server.js page and the middleware is on reqdata.js page.

Comment: perhaps wrap the actual route under io.on

Comment: to be honest, this is the first time I am using WebSocket, so I have no idea how to do what you just said. Can you point me to any reference doc.

Comment: Unfortunately socket io is a black art. It's doc sucks and is extremely confusing. What I mean is something like `io.on('connection', (socket) => { router.get('/routeurl', (req,res)=> {socket.emit(msg,res)})}`

Comment: ah ok, now I get what you're saying. That would be messy but I will try. Thanks! Will get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: Ok. Let me know how it goes :-)